# Apache not displaying custom 500 error page for php errors

Tags: php, apache-2.4, 500-error

Apache does not want to display a custom error document that I have setup.

In my vhost I have

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site/public
    ...
    ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
```

The 500.html is located in /var/www/site/public/500.html

To test this I have just created a broken php page that does return a 500 header but the page is blank. I suspect that this is a result of php generating the 500 page and not apache. So how do I get php to show my custom apache error document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior, as PHP errors aren't considered 5xx Server Errors. According to [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231)

> 6.6.  Server Error 5xx
>
> The 5xx (Server Error) class of status code indicates that the
> server is aware that it has erred or is incapable of performing the
> requested method. - -
>
> 6.6.1.  500 Internal Server Error
>
> The 500 (Internal Server Error) status code indicates that the
> server    encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from
> fulfilling    the request.

PHP errors should always be fixed as they may pose you security problems. For the same reason best practise in handling php errors is to log them for the programmers to review and hide them from users. This kind of setup would be (in php.ini format):

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
log_errors = On
display_errors = Off
```

This will log errors in web server's error log or in other error log configured. Instead of reading them from the site you can perform `tail -f` on the log file during loading the page.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. One cannot "fix" an error the same instant it occurred. And setting display_errors to off will trigger the very 500 error that this very question is about.

Comment: The error will be in logs... where it should be.

Comment: The question here IS NOT about where the text of the error message should be but what should be displayed to a site user. There are some strange people that are browsing your site, you know

Comment: PHP will show blank page / section, depending on the case. This answer is from 2015. At least back then there weren't any `5xx` errors regarding errors in PHP syntax.

Comment: SO the QUESTION was how to show anything but a blank page.

Comment: Then, be welcome to write a better answer. :)

Comment: I will. But when I see a hosting provider support referencing this answer... WTF?